# CSS: How to prevent empty cells in grid (by removing partially empty rows)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a grid of divs that all need to be X pixels wide, with as many rows as needed to fit all of them. I don't know the width of the outer div. This is easy to accomplish using css grid:

```css
#container {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 170px;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  
}

#container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Now, my issue is that I don't want there to be any empty cells in my grid (for aesthetic reasons). So I want to hide all elements on the last row, as shown here:

[image: Example image]

Note that having the grid fit 3 columns is just a special case of the problem: If I can fit 5 columns in the grid, I want to remove all items on the second row.

**Is is possible to achieve this in CSS?** Ideally without manually adding media breakpoints and hiding items in css manually?

If not, can it be solved using Javascript?

*Note that altough I used css `display:grid` in my example, this is not required - all I want is something that looks like a grid.*

Comment: No, CSS can't detect overflow etc so you need Javascript

Comment: Not knowing the number of columns is the killer here. With :nth-child and :last, you can detect if the row is full or not... You would need media queries to hide based on the number of colums.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to achieve using only CSS.
It could be if you had separated rows in html like that:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
</div>
```

And be sure that first cell in row will be that **empty one**
Then you could write CSS selectors using pseudo selector `:empty` and general sibling selector `~`

```css
.row {
  display: block;
}

.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 25px;
  background: yellow;
}

.cell:empty,
.cell:empty ~ .cell {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
</div>
```

Other way is to use javascript which should be kinda trivial

```js
const hideRowIfAnyCellEmpty = () => {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    if (hasRowEmptyCell(row)){
      row.classList.add('has-empty-cell');
    }
  });
}

const hasRowEmptyCell = (row) => {
  return row.querySelectorAll('.cell:empty').length;
};

hideRowIfAnyCellEmpty();
```

```css
.row {
  display: block;
}

.row.has-empty-cell {
  display: none;
}

.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 25px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I haven't seen the :empty selector before, intresting. However since I don't know the number of columns up front I can no render the HTML in this way.

Answer (score 0):

One hack is to consider a pseudo element that will hide them. Of course, you will not have transparency and your element will not fit the height of the container.

```css
#container {
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 170px;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  
}

#container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#container:after {
  content:"";
  background:#fff;
  margin-left:-100vw;
  margin-right:20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Temani! Unfortunetly in my case I want to show another element directly below it, so hiding it by putting something in front does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems it's not possible with CSS only, in the end I decided to solve this using javascript, like this:

```js
var cg = document.getElementById('container');

var style = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(style);

var hideHalfEmptyColumns = function() {
  // How many columns it's gonna be
  var columns = Math.floor(cg.offsetWidth / 50);
  // How many elements are showing
  var elements = cg.childElementCount;
  // How many cells are on completely filled rows
  var elementsToShow = columns * Math.floor(elements / columns);
  style.innerHTML = `
            #container>div:nth-child(n + ${elementsToShow+1}) {
                display: none;
            }`;
}

// In the real world I'd run this on the window resize event as well, but since elements does not have this function the example is a bit broken
hideHalfEmptyColumns();
```

```css
#container {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 170px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50px, 1fr));
}

#container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```